# AdMob ads with a WebView in the same layout?

Tags: android, webview, admob

I'm trying to implement AdMob ads with a WebView.  For the life of me, I can't get anything to show, even in the logs.  It's almost like the ads are not being called at all - my AdMob account shows no requests.  At first I was thinking the WebView was just taking up all the space in the layout, but now I'm second guessing myself, because I'm not seeing any LogCat output relating to ads.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 ads:adUnitId="[myIDishere]"
                 ads:adSize="BANNER"
                 ads:testDevices="[myhashishere]"
                 ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
  <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

And then my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



//StartServicesCheck


private boolean checkPlayServices() {
      int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
      if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
          showErrorDialog(status);
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported.", 
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          finish();
        }
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    } 

    void showErrorDialog(int code) {
      GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(code, this, 
          REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();
    }

    static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 1001;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES:
          if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services must be installed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
          }
          return;
      }
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



//EndServicesCheck

private WebView mWebview ;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebview.canGoBack() == true){
        mWebview.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


public class BannerExample extends Activity {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
      }
    }


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mWebview  = new WebView(this);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
    mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        mWebview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    }

    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mWebview .loadUrl("[webpagehere]");
    setContentView(mWebview );


    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mWebview.scrollTo(681, 100);
        }

    }
    );

}
```

}

Do I have something wrong in my coding itself?  I'm kind of leaning that way because I'm not seeing requests or log output.

Comment: wait a sec, your code is messed up. You have defined the Banner activity inside MainActivity??
Create one activity only..

Answer (score 2):

Change the `WebView` to the following. Your `AdView` is being hidden by the `WebView`:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

I would also suggest to set the width of `AdView` to match_parent and `adSize` as `"SMART_BANNER"`
SMART_BANNER ads automatically resize themselves according to the orientation and width od the device.

**EDIT**

I just went through your code. It had many small mistakes. change it to the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



//StartServicesCheck

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
mWebview  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    mWebview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
}

final Activity activity = this;

mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

mWebview .loadUrl("[webpagehere]");
setContentView(mWebview );


mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        mWebview.scrollTo(681, 100);
    }

}
);

}


private boolean checkPlayServices() {
  int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
  if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
      showErrorDialog(status);
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported.", 
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      finish();
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
} 

void showErrorDialog(int code) {
  GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(code, this, 
      REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES).show();
}

static final int REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES = 1001;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_PLAY_SERVICES:
      if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services must be installed.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
      }
      return;
  }
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}



//EndServicesCheck

private WebView mWebview ;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebview.canGoBack() == true){
        mWebview.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}




}
```

PS: Sorry for the messed up indentation :P

Comment: I just made all those changes, and I'm still not seeing it :(  In logcat I still don't see any mention of the ads trying to load.. :(

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.  So, I implemented your changes, and the app just crashes immediately.  Logcat is stating this: `06-18 11:36:54.380: E/AndroidRuntime(27310): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.iamthesquidward.ferris-14.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.iamthesquidward.ferris-14, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]`.  I assume that it can't find any of the AdMob references, even though I've tried copying the jar to libs and referencing the Play Services SDK

Comment: Make sure you have added Google Play services properly and Replace your adview with the one from Play services i.e. com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.

Check this link: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals